# Can the directional coupler phenomena of the light jumping between waveguides, be derived and explained without quantum mechanics?

Tags: optics, maxwell-equations

Where in the Maxwell Equations it can be seen that the modes can jump between two waveguides in close proximity to each other? Below is coupling coefficient between mode $\nu$ and mode $\mu$:
$$
\tag{42}\tilde{\kappa}_{\nu\mu}=\omega\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}}_\nu^*\cdot\Delta\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_\mu\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}}_\mu\text{d}x\text{d}y
$$
Directional couplers can be used in Telecommunications to create an optical switch. But I have a problem with understanding the physical phenomena that makes it possible: the lightwave mode can jump between two waveguides placed in close proximity to each other, but how can it be explained in a Feynmaneese way? All I've found were mathematical formulas derived from Maxwell's Equations - however, I got the impression the phenomena itself is not of a classical nature, and in order to arrive at the equations, some dubious assumptions must first be made, that come from empiric observations.

Quantum explanation would be along the lines of Power Exchange I suppose. But does a classical explanation exist? I would suppose something along the lines of "when the environment for mode propagation is the same in two adjacent waveguides that are within the range of the field of the wave that is strong enough to allow the transfer, the energy of the wave can be pulled towards the other waveguide", but what principle, law, theorem to base it upon?

Comment: diffraction and interference

Comment: Do you see Planck's constant anywhere in this phenomenon? If not, why would it require quantum mechanics?

Comment: hi @hyportnex, could you please elaborate? The two modes traversing parallel waveguides don't quite touch each other at any point (no indice), as it would be required for the principle of superposition of waves in interference for two waves to exchange amplitudes? Also would interference mean that in the other waveguide, actually there is a mode traversing it all the time, but it's amplitude is zero or such of the wave from the other waveguide when it jumps switching waveguides?

Comment: hi @FlatterMann because I cannot see a "sensible" explanation of a wave "teleporting" from one place to another with the entirety of its power, just getting slightly distorted, I assumed there must be some "quantum magic" involved. If there is no need for magic, then the trouble that I have would be to interpret the mathematics of Maxwell equations in a way to understand the physics in a descriptive way

Comment: Maxwell's equations explain it perfectly fine.

Comment: Okay then I suppose my question is "how" now that the answer to "whether" is stated. I am unable to see the how directly in the articles deriving the maths, as I am an amateur enthusiast, but as such I for sure need to study it more thoroughly.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers especially "Transmission line types" and "Waveguide types"